# Datatable output not showing correctly in console

Tags: r, datatable, console, output

I have a large datatable (panel), which shows correctly in the console when I use its name. However, something very odd happens if I start filtering.
If I use any filter, for example by showing only the first 5 columns, or by filtering for a specific year, etc., one of the columns (the name of the observation, which is of type character) seems to bug out completely. I get an extremely large output for this column, with many tabstops ("\t") included. It seems to also allocate information from the other columns somehow. The rest of the columns work correctly.
I cannot share the data unfortunately. Any idea how this can happen? As the data shows correctly as a whole, and the datatype (character) is also correct, I have no idea how to fix this.
The data came from a txt file, was read in via `read.table(path, sep = "\t" , header = T , fill = TRUE,na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F)` and then converted via `setDT`

Comment: Could you provide dummy data similar in structure to your real data? Difficult to offer much help without ability to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its really hard to do that if I dont know where the issue lies. But I keep you updated if I find anything.

Comment: you could start with showing us the console output (either a screenshot or using reprex). Then give simple example of your "filtering". That should help diagnose the issue for anyone interested in your issue.